# Inline SVG: way to hide plain text from old browsers?

Tags: html, svg

I have some inline SVG code embeded into an HTML page, like:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Some HTML</title></head>
  <body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <text y="20" font-size="20">Some text</text>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there some standard compliant way of masking the text inside the SVG from (old) browsers that don't support SVG?
**Without** using some fancy image replacement technique, Javascript or CSS?

Just some ideas I've had so far (but couldn't get to work):

- Is there some SVG element that accepts text as an *attribute* and displays it?
- Is there some way to mask the beginning and end of a comment tag, so that the SVG parser doesn't see it but the HTML does?
- Is there some way to seperately insert the beginning and end of some html tag into the svg without displaying it?

Comment: I haven't tried any of the techniques but  CSS-Tricks has a [guide](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-svg-fallbacks/). Though I don't think they cover your use case.

Comment: BTW, the traditional trick used for `<script>` and `<style>` tags (wrapping it all in an HTML comment) was apparently never implemented for `<svg>`.

Comment: What old browsers are you trying to support? Any browser too old to support SVG is too dangerous to use on the public internet?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  I read several articles on CSS-Tricks, none covers what I want.

Comment: @RobertLongson Just any browser that ever was :D ... and search robots and accessibility technologies ...

Comment: @RobertLongson I can't speak for Chris but there're email clients, home-brew scrapers, RSS readers, search indexers... and of course old and dangerous browsers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles onto this page, who has the same question: this isn't really an *answer* to the question, just a *workaround* for the underlying problem (until hopefully, someone comes up with a *real* solution):

I actually added some *more* information to the SVG, that makes sense on it's own, but also in combination with the other text parts, like:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Some HTML</title></head>
  <body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <desc>
        Some website is displayed on a computer monitor. 
        The locationbar reads: 
      </desc>
      <text x="25" y="40" font-size="16">http://example.com/</text>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/desc